# Search on particular side of a String with RegExp

Tags: regex

I have a long string that contains information like this:

`|infoId-*-info||infoId-*-info||infoId-*-info| ...`

I use the `'-*-'` character as seperator and I want to make searching just on right side of `'-*-'` character but it should return whole part of `infoId-*-info` if it match any `info` , is there anyway to do that?

Thanks in advance

Example:

This is my String :

```
|8d9f9a0g9r8ad8f-*-sedat||0sdf7a89s9d0wg-*-derya||9g7a6w6e7d89awwe-*-caner|
```

for this string if my search value is `"edat"` how can I return whole `8d9f9a0g9r8ad8f-*-sedat` string, and if my search value is `"s"` it shouldnt return also `0sdf7a89s9d0wg-*-derya` because of left side of `"-*-"` contains `"s"` character.
If u can give me [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) link that supports this example it will be very wellcomed thanks so much for spending time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need something along the lines of

```
/((?:infoId)\/YOUR_REGEX_FOR_INFO)\s/
```

(we don't know how your `infoId` and `info` are structured).

**EDIT** following the example added by OP

You can use (for `edat`):

```
/\|([^-]+-\*-[^|]*edat[^|]*\|/
```

I don't know which language you are using but you can use the "global" flag to get all matches in the string at once. If it's JS, it will be `/\|([^-]+-\*-[^|]*edat[^|]*\|/g`.

Comment: I added an example can u check it again pls, because I couldnt use your answer

Comment: Its for jquery, sorry for not inform that :S

Comment: I tried this http://jsfiddle.net/XNz6s/ can u check it, its not working exactly what I want and I am very bad at RegExp, can u check where am I missing pls?

Comment: You need proper escaping and the "g" flag, see the updated version: http://jsfiddle.net/XNz6s/3/

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

`(?s)(?<=/)[^/]+(?=/|$)`

**Explanation:**

```
<!--
(?s)(?<=/)[^/]+(?=/|$)

Options: ^ and $ match at line breaks

Match the remainder of the regex with the options: dot matches newline (s) «(?s)»
Assert that the regex below can be matched, with the match ending at this position (positive lookbehind) «(?<=/)»
   Match the character “/” literally «/»
Match any character that is NOT a “/” «[^/]+»
   Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
Assert that the regex below can be matched, starting at this position (positive lookahead) «(?=/|$)»
   Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «/»
      Match the character “/” literally «/»
   Or match regular expression number 2 below (the entire group fails if this one fails to match) «$»
      Assert position at the end of a line (at the end of the string or before a line break character) «$»
-->
```

Comment: I added an example can u check it again pls, because I couldnt use your answer

Comment: Try ``(?s)(?<=\|\|)[^/]+(?=\|\||$)``[generic] or may be ``(?s)(?<=\|{2})[^/]+(?=\|{2}|$)`` [.NET supports, not PCRE].

Comment: can u just give me a jsfiddle link that support the example that I wrote above , I know I spend your time but I need it pls help :)